# C# generate intermediate certificate from self signed Root CA

Tags: c#, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with c# and `Bouncy Castle` in version `1.8.5`.
I was successfully able to generate a `Certificate Authority` (CA) and now want to generate an `Intermediate Certificate`.
In my current workflow, the CA certificate is returned as a `X509Certificate2`-object that I pass over to generate the intermediate certificate.
From there I want to read the `PrivateKey` but I have troubles doing so.

For CA generation (the `CACertificateDetails` is a simple class for storing strings to pass over):

```
public static X509Certificate2 GenerateCA(CACertificateDetails details)
{
    // generate a random number
    var random = GetSecureRandom();

    // init the certificate generator
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    // serial number
    certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(SerialNumber(random));

    // set issuer and subject name
    var subjectDN = new X509Name(details.SubjectName);
    var issuerDN = new X509Name(details.IssuerName);
    certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
    certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

    // validation time
    var notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    var notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(details.ValidYears);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

    // subject public Key
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
    KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, details.KeyStrength);
    RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

    certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

    // set the hash algorithm
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;
    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha512WithRsaEncryption.ToString(), issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

    // generate the certificate
    var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
    var x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

    PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);
    Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.ParsePrivateKey().GetDerEncoded());
    if (seq.Count != 9)
    {
        throw new PemException("malformed sequence in RSA private key");
    }

    RsaPrivateKeyStructure rsa = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(seq);
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

    var convertedRsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
    var x509CertificateRet = x509Certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(convertedRsa);
    x509CertificateRet.FriendlyName = details.FriendlyName;

    return x509CertificateRet;
}
```

The method to generate the intermediate certificate is as follows (the just generated CA is passed as a object now):

```
public static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificate(CertificateDetails details, X509Certificate2 issuer)
{
    // generate a random number
    var random = GetSecureRandom();

    // init the certificate generator
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    // serial number
    certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(SerialNumber(random));

    // set issuer and subject name
    var issuerDN = new X509Name(issuer.Issuer);
    certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);

    var distinguishedNames = DistinguishedName(details);
    var nameOids = new ArrayList(distinguishedNames.Select(x => x.Item1).ToArray());
    var nameValues = new ArrayList(distinguishedNames.Select(x => x.Item2).ToArray());
    var subjectDN = new X509Name(nameOids, nameValues);
    certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

    // authority key identifier
    var authorityKeyIdentifier = new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(issuer));
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id, false, authorityKeyIdentifier);

    // Basic Constraints - certificate is allowed to be used as intermediate.
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints.Id, true, new BasicConstraints(details.IsIntermediateCertificate));

    // key usage
    if (!details.IsIntermediateCertificate)
    {
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.DataEncipherment | KeyUsage.KeyAgreement));
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(new[] { KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth, KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth }));
    }
    else
    {
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.DataEncipherment | KeyUsage.KeyAgreement | KeyUsage.KeyCertSign));
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeID.AnyExtendedKeyUsage));
    }

    // validation time
    var notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    var notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(details.ValidYears);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

    // subject public Key
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
    KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, details.KeyStrength);
    RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

    certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

    // set the hash algorithm
    var issuerPrivateKey = TransformRSAPrivateKey(issuer.PrivateKey);
    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA3-512withRSA", issuerPrivateKey, random);

    // generate the certificate
    var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

    PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);
    var x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

    Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.ParsePrivateKey().GetDerEncoded());
    if (seq.Count != 9)
    {
        throw new PemException("Malformed sequence in RSA private key");
    }

    RsaPrivateKeyStructure rsa = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(seq);
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

    x509Certificate.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
    x509Certificate.FriendlyName = details.FriendlyName;

    return x509Certificate;
}
```

I now fail at function `TransformRSAPrivateKey` in line `prov.ExportParameters(true)` probably because there is no private key data found, which I find strange due to the fact that I copied it with `x509Certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(convertedRsa)` in the CA generation.

```
private static AsymmetricKeyParameter TransformRSAPrivateKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = privateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    RSAParameters parameters = prov.ExportParameters(true);

    return new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.Modulus),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.Exponent),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.D),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.P),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.Q),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.DP),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.DQ),
        new BigInteger(1, parameters.InverseQ));
}
```

How can I proceed to use the CA to generate (and sign) my `Intermediate Certificate`?
I do not want to pass the `AsymmetricKeyParameter` as seen in multiple examples here on stackoverflow.
At some point I want to maybe save the CA to the disk and read it at another time to generate a certificate with the same CA. At that time I won't have the CA generation workflow and therefore not the `AsymmetricKeyParameter` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the issue was in these lines:

```
// set the hash algorithm
var issuerPrivateKey = TransformRSAPrivateKey(issuer.PrivateKey);
ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA3-512withRSA", issuerPrivateKey, random);
```

One can pass the `X509Certificate2` issuer certificate to the `GenerateCertificate` function as in the original post.
The trick is to load that certificate with the flag `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable`, like `X509Certificate2(certificatePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);`.

Further I changed my code to

```
// set the hash algorithm
var issuerPrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(issuerCA.PrivateKey).Private;
ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha512WithRsaEncryption.ToString(), issuerPrivateKey, random);
```